# How can I enter Mongo as a superuser or reset users?

Tags: mongodb

I'm was playing around with permissions and locked myself out of Mongo database.  I'm pretty sure I did this by trying to explicitly add access to a database but instead I overwrote only allowing permission to the database. So I'm effectively locked out of my Mongo database and everything I read tells me how to create a super user if I have the add user privilege.  Right now I don't think I have any users that have that privilege.  Is there a way to enter the database as all access?  I own the server and have root access.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you have locked yourself out then you need to do the following:

1. Stop your MongoDB instance
2. Remove the --auth and/or --keyfile options from your MongoDB config to disable authentication
3. Start the instance without authentication
4. Edit the users as needed
5. Restart the instance with authentication enabled

Comment: Removing auth was not enough indeed, thanks!

Comment: `keyFile` implies `security.authorization`, thus you must remove both.

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar issue when I created a user without adding a superuser first. The following steps helped solve the problem:

1. Open the MongoDB configuration file using `sudo` (`sudo vi mongodb.conf`).
   The file can be found in `/etc/` folder.
2. Comment `"auth = true"`.
3. Stop the MongoDB service (`sudo service mongod stop`)
4. Start the MongoDB service (`sudo service mongod start`)
5. Then create "root" superuser using the below command:

   ```
   use admin

   db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"password",roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin"}]});
   ```

   For reference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#superuser-roles
6. Go back and uncomment `"auth=true"`. Stop and Start/Restart the mongodb service.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I've been stuck trying to figure this out when I uploaded the project to the dev server. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Ditto. Server error messages spectacularly unhelpful on this. Thank you!

Comment: I'm using AWS EC2 linux instance and under /etc/ there is mongod.conf and not mongodb.conf. Also I didn't find auth = true entry in the conf file. please clarify

Answer (score 17):

If you use a [replica set with a `keyfile`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/#create-a-keyfile)

> Security between members of the replica set using Internal
>   Authentication

Keyfile is used for auth in replication.

```
security:
  keyFile: <path-to-keyfile>
replication:
  replSetName: <replicaSetName>
```

You can use this command to login as a admin to mongod:

```
mongo -u __system -p "$(tr -d '\011-\015\040' < path-to-keyfile)" --authenticationDatabase local
```

Afterword you are able to create or modify your admin user.

> Internal Role
>
> `__system` MongoDB assigns this role to user objects that represent cluster members, such as replica set members and mongos instances. The
>   role entitles its holder to take any action against any object in the
>   database.
>
> Do not assign this role to user objects representing applications or
>   human administrators, other than in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: Where did you find this information?

Comment: @octohedron The last file in this diff shows it: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/eb3435c25eabc90e2c4ff7c331c94c4c222d0b7e Another source is https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/12/mongodb-security-vs-five-bad-guys/

Comment: your method with keyfile worked for me on MongoDB hosted in Kubernetes Engine from GCP, as I did not want to restart mongodb like in the OP's accepted answer. For some reason I was unable to exec directly into the pod using kubectl, but I was able to first "gcloud ssh" into the node, and then using root and "docker ps" available on the host, I found the internal container name, and was able to exec into the container from there instead. GCP seems to have already created a keyfile in my case, and I could see it from 'ps aux', so I reused it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the answers to this question, they might help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117104/mongodb-root-user

Basically if you still have access to the server, you may be able to access the `Admin` database.

There's more in this page http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/user-privileges/

Note that 2.6 version changes how this works completely. For 2.6 you'll need to spend more time with http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/

Comment: As mentioned in the post, that's the only info I've been able to find.  I don't have permissions to do that

Answer (score 0):

@Divya's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159525/260283) helped but was not complete for me. Here's what I had to do:

#### Steps

1. Connect to the machine that was hosting my MongoDB instance
2. Open the MongoDB configuration file found in `/etc/` folder using: `sudo nano mongod.conf`
3. Comment out the following code like so:

   ```
   # security:
   #   authorization: enabled
   ```
4. Stop the MongoDB service: `sudo service mongod stop`
5. Start the MongoDB service: `sudo service mongod start`
6. Connect to the database using Robo3T or equivalent. With a connection to the **admin** collection, create a new admin superuser:

   ```
   db.createUser({ user:"admin", pwd:"password", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}] });
   ```
7. Go back and uncomment the lines from step 3. Then repeat steps 4 and 5.
8. You should now be able to authenticate with the new user you created in step 6 and have full access to the database.

#### Troubleshooting

- If for whatever reason, after trying to restart your mongo service, you cannot connect to it, you can make sure the service properly started with: `systemctl --type=service --state=active`. If it has started, it will be in the list as `mongod.service`.
- Mongo logs can also be found at `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` but this is less likely to be helpful in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

You have to stop Mongo, remove the admin files, then start Mongo

```
sudo service mongod stop
mv /data/admin.* .
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: This is destroying the administrative users database and allowing access via the "localHostExcetption" it is not a good way to administer users when you have a problem.

Comment: This will destroy your database!