# Bitnami mongod fails with 'MongoServerSelectionError'

Tags: mongodb, linux, command-line, bitnami

Bitnami's Mongo image launched under *virtualbox* works and brings up the text console (debian11 so no X11). Debian instance starts the listener correctly according to **ss -atpn**. But starting **mongosh** with mongodb uri or switches fails with 'Server selection timed out after 2000 ms'. I invoke **mongosh** by the commandline NOT from Javascript.
How do I solve this error?
what are the different default databases?    (Passwords mean nothing here)

- [How can I enter Mongo as a superuser or reset users?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62976/how-can-i-enter-mongo-as-a-superuser-or-reset-users)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162342/mongodb-connection-error-mongotimeouterror-server-selection-timed-out-after-30
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850039/mongodb-error-on-connection-mongoservers

Comment: `I invoke mongosh by the commandline NOT from Javascript.` - what command, exactly do you issue - remember, the more detail you include in your question, the more people can help you!